# Pass Interference Behind Scrimmage

Tags: rules, american-football

What if a receiver or a running back is behind the line of scrimmage can a defensive player step across the line of scrimmage to attack the player? Does the defensive player need to allow him to touch the ball before he makes contact or can he immediately collide with him regardless of whether the ball has been thrown or not?

Answer (score 0):

NFL - No foul for contact behind the line of scrimmage.  Contact which is otherwise legal is allowed up to 1 yard past the line of scrimmage. I think (but am not 100% certain) that this is true in NFHS and NCAA as well.

Comment: Welcome to Sports SE - to make this a stronger answer, are you able to reference the specific rule in the NFL Rulebook which supports this?